# Передача переменной по средствам ссылки и разметки parse_mode='Markdown'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, markdown

Я понимаю что возможно мой вопрос будет весьма простым для кого то, но я уже сижу не первый чес и не могу понять в чем проблема

Задача передать через ссылку profile_link, user_id в функцию show_search_user
Я пробовал уже много чего. и / и без и помещать все в квадратные скобки, ничего не помогает.
Из базы данных данные берутся корректно Print() благополучно это показывает.
Но почему то bot.send_message корректно не формируется и выдает раз раз за разом ошибку.
Подскажите в чем тут проблема! Буду очень благодарен!

```
    user_data_list = []
    for user in result:
        profile_link = f"[профиль](/show_search_user/ {user['user_id']})"
        user_data_list.append(f"{user['user_id']} | {user['fio']} | @{user['user_name']}\n"
                              f">>{user['prof']} | {profile_link}")

    print(user_data_list)

    if user_data_list:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "\n".join(user_data_list), parse_mode='Markdown')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.', parse_mode='Markdown')
```